# ¿Cómo obtengo el name de una etiqueta en WordPress teniendo el slug?

Tags: wordpress

Quisiera saber como obtengo el name (nombre de la etiqueta). Tengo el slug de dicha etiqueta.

Por ejemplo

> Name: Categoría 1
>
> Slug: categoria-1

Yo tengo el categoria-1 y necesito obtener el Categoría 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sólo para completar la respuesta. Ya que el uso de `get_term_by()` es mucho más amplio y puede sernos útil en varios casos.

Esta respuesta es una traducción del [Manual de Referencia de Wordpress](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by).

La función `get_term_by()` de Wordpress obtiene todos los datos de un Término de la base de datos mediante el campo `term`.

La sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
<?php get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter ) ?>
```

Si `$value` no existe la función devolverá `false`. Si `$taxonomy` existe y existen `$field` y `$value`, el término será devuelto.

#### Parámetros:

- `$field` (string) (requerido):  Puede ser 'id', 'slug', 'name', or 'term_taxonomy_id'
  El valor por defecto es: 'id'
- `$value` (string|integer) (required) Valor a buscar
  Valor por defecto: Ninguno
- `$taxonomy`: (string) (optional) Nombre de la taxonomía `category`, `post_tag`, `link_category`, `nav_menu` u otro personalizado
  Valor por defecto: '' (cadena vacía)
- `$output`:(string) (optional) Constante OBJECT, ARRAY_A, or ARRAY_N
  Valor por defecto: OBJECT
- `$filter`: (string) (optional) El valor predeterminado es raw o no se aplicará ningún filtro definido por WordPress.
  Valor por defecto: 'raw'

#### Valores devueltos

(mixto)
Fila del Término (objeto o matriz) obtenida de la base de datos. Devolverá `false` si `$taxonomy` no existe o si `$term` no se ha encontrado. En caso contrario, devuelve el objeto (por defecto) o una matriz de campos dependiendo del parámetro `$output`.

> Es decir, que la función sirve para devolver no sólo el nombre, sino
>   cualquiera de los valores siguientes:

Los campos devueltos son:

- term_id (Ver advertencia más abajo)
- name
- slug
- term_group
- term_taxonomy_id
- taxonomy
- description
- parent
- count

**Advertencia:** ¡confusión string vs integer! Los valores de campo, incluido term_id, se devuelven en formato de cadena. Antes de usarlos más adelante haga las conversiones que sean necesarias.

#### Ejemplos de uso

```
// Obtener  term por el name ''news'' en la taxonomía Categories.
$category = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'category')

// Obtener term por name ''news'' en la taxonomía Etiquetas (Tags).
$tag = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'post_tag')

// Obtener term por name ''news'' en taxonomía personalizada.
$term = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'my_custom_taxonomy')

// Obtener term por name ''Default Menu'' desde los menúes del tema (theme's nav menus).
// (Alternativa al uso de wp_get_nav_menu_items)
$menu = get_term_by('name', 'Default Menu', 'nav_menu');
```

Obtener los terms de un post usando su id:

```
// Get term by name ''news'' in Categories taxonomy.
$category = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'category')

// Get term by name ''news'' in Tags taxonomy.
$tag = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'post_tag')

// Get term by name ''news'' in Custom taxonomy.
$term = get_term_by('name', 'news', 'my_custom_taxonomy')

// Get term by name ''Default Menu'' from theme's nav menus.
// (Alternative to using wp_get_nav_menu_items)
$menu = get_term_by('name', 'Default Menu', 'nav_menu');
```

Answer (score 2):

Ya lo pude resolver! Lo hice así:

```
$res1=categoria-1;

$term = get_term_by('slug', $rest1, 'post_tag');

$nom_tags1 = $term->name;
```